# Exclusion from general-purpose exception chaining facility in 'remote' exceptions

Tags: java, jms, rmi, rpc

Consider any of '*remote*' exceptions:
`javax.jms.JMSException` or `java.rmi.RemoteException`
both exclude from common pattern of exception chaining by for having *detail* or *linked exception* properties.
When you print stack trace containing one of this exceptions you'll get trimmed stack trace. To get *full* stack trace you need additional dancing with tambourines.

What is the reason *remote* exceptions to be designed this way?

EDIT:

I'm browsing sources of java 1.6.0_26. Look on two arguments constructor `public RemoteException(String s, Throwable cause)` of `java.rmi.RemoteException`. You can see next code `initCause(null);  // Disallow subsequent initCause`. This seems to be intentional decision in Java SE 6 to do that.
**But** acording to [common practice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html) `initCause()` has it's grand purpose to construct *exceptions chain*!
I don't remember the source but I'm confident about best practice of creating custom exception:
1. Expose all of the constructors of super class
2. Don't brake *exceptions chain* (call `Throwable.initCause()` in other words). This could be simply achived by calling super constructor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Guess it's time to update your java :)

> As of release 1.4, this exception has been retrofitted to conform to the general purpose exception-chaining mechanism. The "wrapped remote exception" that may be provided at construction time and accessed via the public detail field is now known as the cause, and may be accessed via the Throwable.getCause() method, as well as the aforementioned "legacy field."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/rmi/RemoteException.html

EDIT:

and to answer your question as well: it was a bad design decision, which got corrected in 1.4

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gergely Szilagyi! Could you take a look at updated question plesase.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on a false premiss. Every exception from `Throwable` upwards has a [getCause()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29) method.

Comment: But prior to 1.4 it wasn't filled with the real cause in `RemoteException`.

Comment: @GergelySzilagyi Agreed but why the 'but'? This just reinforces the answer. (a) The behaviour isn't unique to these exception classes; (b) prior to 1.4 the behaviour didn't even exist in those classes. In both cases the question is based on a false premiss.